# Best approach to streamvideo from android to PC

Tags: android, live-streaming

Hello
I've been trying to stream video (Like webcam) from android phone ( 2.2 ) to a PC, yet without success, I've seen so many approches " Sipdroid, IMdroid " depend on reading the output of MediaRecorder and manipulates it to make it streamable, Droidcam, IPcam - which uses preview frames ( I supposed that because they stream in M-JPEG format)- even ffmpeg was suggested wich would access the video4linux cam directly - away from the os -.

I guess for my case M-jpeg streaming is the simplest approach but till now I couldn't find any open source app that implements it.
can anyone help ? can anyone suggest a simple code to stream video live from android phone to pc throw RTP, HTTP or any other possible protocol ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

http://code.google.com/p/camdroiduni/

http://code.google.com/p/camdroiduni/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fcode%2Feclipse_workspace%2FPhotoCamDroid

I hope this will help you !!!

Answer (score 0):

The above given link http://code.google.com/p/camdroiduni/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fcode%2Feclipse_workspace%2FPhotoCamDroid 
donot work